# Ping and General Structure C# - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ping

Initially let me give an overview of my application. I am attempting to use Visual C# to do a PING on an address the user specifies. The user interacts with the system by entering the address they wish to PING into the textbox - the user then clicks the pingButton which will ping the desired address and then return the results to the user via a message box.

This is just the initial stage of the application.

I am having problem with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace Ping_Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int timeOut = 300;
            int ttl = 300;
            string stat = "", data = "[012345678901234567890123456789]";
            PingOptions pingOpts = new PingOptions();
            pingOpts.Ttl = ttl;
            pingOpts.DontFragment = true;
            Ping pinger = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = pinger.Send(pingAddressTextBox.Equals, timeOut, Buffer, pingOpts);
            if (reply.Status.ToString() != "Success")
                stat = "Failed";
            else
                stat = reply.Status.ToString();
            pinger.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Congratulations!");
        }
    }
}
```

This code is from another topic on stack overflow - I am trying to gain an understanding by getting the code working and then modifying it.

The errors are:

Error   1   'System.Buffer' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Net.IPAddress'
Error   4   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Buffer'to 'byte[]'
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(System.Net.IPAddress, int, byte[], System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions)' has some invalid
   arguments

As I say I am just learning - this is just for a bit of a laugh - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an object of type `Buffer` to pass to `pinger.Send`.

Here you just have the type name. You need an actual `byte` array:

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping ();

// Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);

// Wait 10 seconds for a reply.
int timeout = 10000;

// Set options for transmission:
// The data can go through 64 gateways or routers
// before it is destroyed, and the data packet
// cannot be fragmented.
PingOptions options = new PingOptions (64, true);

// Send the request.
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send ("www.contoso.com", timeout, buffer, options);
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144956.aspx)

Here `buffer` is created from the string. You're missing this step.